# How to pass JavaScript output as a POST request to PHP? [Getting TZ using js and then sending to mySQL]

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, codeigniter

How to pass JavaScript output as a POST request to PHP. [Getting TZ using js and then sending to mySQL]

using [Automatic Timezone Detection Using Javascript](http://pellepim.bitbucket.org/jstz/)

```
<script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>js/tzdetect/jstz.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var timezone = jstz.determine();
    timezone.name();
</script>
```

the .name() method outputs the user's local timezone which I will then pass to the server/mySQL via a POST request.

I'm also using CodeIgniter's Active records functions so as to minimize/eliminate any possible sql injections if the user tries to mess with the javascript code.

I know I can put a variable from PHP to javascript, but not the other way around. How does one go about doing this? is AJAX required? I do not have any exxperience with ajax. it looks very intimidating tbh.

EDIT: Also, to be clear, I'm submitting the form the normal way, all I need is that timezone.

Comment: you always need to use ajax whenever you want to send client data to server without page refresh/ by submitting the data as form submit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given your update, you should have a hidden form field:

`<input id="tz" type="hidden" name="timezone" value="unknown" />`

Then you can add the timezone programmatically:

```
<script>
    var timezone = jstz.determine();
    // set the value of your hidden timezone field to the correct value
    document.getElementById('tz').value = timezone.name();
</script>
```

Comment: Huh. This was much simpler [imo] than the ajax method. Which, in your opinion, would be the most convenient? I wish I could up all of your answers.

Comment: Before your edit, the assumption was that you only wanted to send the timezone to your server and that it would happen asynchronously (without reloading the page). If you are already submitting the form synchronously though, there is no need to use AJAX. They are both pretty convenient and easy, but in this instance AJAX doesn't make sense. Read up on AJAX though, it is used universally and allows for better user experiences. Don't be intimidated by it, it's the same as regular GET and POST requests, just removes the page reload.

Answer (score 0):

AJAX is going to be the way to go. If you're intimidated, a good place to start might be with jQuery. You can do something like

```
var data = new Object();
data.tz = timezone.name();

$.post("ajaxendpoint.php",
       data,
       function() {
           // do something after ajax completes if you want
       });
```

In `ajaxendpoint.php`, you can then get the timezone:

```
<?php
$timezone = $_POST['tz'];
```

I recommend not just pasting this (it might not work 100% as is even) and reading the [documentation for `$.post()`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/). jQuery makes AJAX super simple though - don't be intimidated!

Answer (score 0):

Using ajax and jQuery you can solve it like this:

```
function sendInfo() {
    var timezone = jstz.determine();

    $.ajax({
        url: "myScript.php",   // URL of your php script
        type: "post",
        data: {timezone: timezone.name()},
        success: function(data) {
            alert("success");
        } 
    });
};
```

and then bind this function to some button. And in your php file (myScript.php) you can get the value like this:

```
<?php
    $timezone = $_POST['timezone'];
    ...
```

Comment: Wouldn't under `data` be `{timezone: timezone.name()}` ? instead of `timezone`, since the name() method outputs the actual value of the timezone?

Comment: This. Or you can simply use jQuery $("myButton").click(function() {}) and put your ajax code inside this function.

Comment: I looked up the .bind() jquery method. What I decided to do was add an ID to the submit button and use .bind(): `$('#submit').bind('click', sendInfo());` I tested it and I noticed that the `success` popped up, even without me clicking submit, was supposed to happen?

Comment: You have to remove brackets from your definition. $("#submit").bind("click", sendInfo); otherwise your function is fired as soon as this line of code is loaded and not when you actually click the button.

Answer (score 0):

```
var timezone = jstz.determine();


$.post("http://www.yoururl.com/page.php", {
  timezone:  timezone.name()

})
  .done(function(data) {
   alert(data); //response from the page.php
  });
```

In page.php file

```
    <?php
        $tz = $_POST['timezone'];
       //Do other thing to store timezone in database
    ?>
```